# NSDate count every monday

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsdate

how can I program a code, which counts every X-day. Like count every monday (or thursday, or whatever) from one NSDate to another (today).
I know, how to get the day of an NSDate by checking

```
    $int weekday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:myDate]weekday];
```

but this isn't helping a bit…

(Of course, I could just calculate all days and / 7, but this isn't working for my project I'm working on…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a while loop starting at the first `NSDate` and ending at the last `NSDate`. Increment by one day each time and check whether the day is equal to the day you want.

```
int counter = 0;
while ([NSDate laterDate:earlyDate:lateDate] == lateDate)
{
     int weekday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:earlyDate]weekday];
     if (weekday == desiredWeekday) counter++;
     earlyDate = [earlyDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600*24];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm just starting with Xcode and Objective-C and this way it is just working! Thanks!